# GitHub pages creating an issue with ReactRouter

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, github, react-context

The URL: https://lakgupta.github.io/gocomet-myntra-assignment

As you can see, the name exactly matches the path but there's a "#/" being added at the end of the URL as soon as it loads which is why my page won't render at all, any fixes?

App.js

```
  <CartProvider>
      <Switch>
        <Route path="/gocomet-myntra-assignment" exact>
          {console.log(cartIsShown)}
          {cartIsShown && <Cart onHide={hideCartHandler}></Cart>},
          <Navbar onClickCart={showCartHandler} onSearch={getSearchTerm} />,
          <Middlebar />,
          <div className="filter-product row">
            {" "}
            <FilterTab></FilterTab>{" "}
            <ProductPage searchTerm={searchedTerm}></ProductPage>{" "}
          </div>
        </Route>
        <Route path="/product/:id">
          {cartIsShown && <Cart onHide={hideCartHandler}></Cart>},
          <ProductDetail onClickCartBtn={showCartHandler}></ProductDetail>
        </Route>
      </Switch>
    </CartProvider>
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding this router. Will redirect to the same URL without the trailing slash.

```
<Redirect from="/:url*(/+)" to={pathname.slice(0, -1)} />
```